# Do names retire in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

When naming my second character in multiplayer I wanted to use the same name as my first, but this is not permitted and it wants unique names for each characters.
[image]

Is this name released for reuse once i retire my character or will i have to come up with new names every time?

Comment: I should test this when I retire my character, Unique Character Name...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can reuse your name once you promote your character.